# how to get sharedpreferences from a radiogroup to anotrher activitys

Tags: android

I have two activities (settings, prayers)

in the settings activity I put three radio buttons inside a radio group every radio button will let the colors changed in the prayers activity

settings.class

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

RadioGroup rg;
TextView textCheckedID, textCheckedIndex;
final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radios);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(rgOnCheckedChangeListener);
    textCheckedID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkedid);
    textCheckedIndex = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.checkedindex);
    LoadPreferences();
}
OnCheckedChangeListener rgOnCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)rg.findViewById(checkedId);
    int checkedIndex = rg.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);
    textCheckedID.setText("checkedID = " + checkedId);
    textCheckedIndex.setText("checkedIndex = " + checkedIndex);
    SavePreferences(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, checkedIndex);

}
};
private void SavePreferences(String key, int value) {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt(key, value);
editor.commit();
}
private void LoadPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
}
}
```

and in the prayers activity the textcolor and the background of the layout should change colors to one of the selected choice in the settings activity

prayers.class

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int colors = sharedPreferences
            .getInt("KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX", 0);
    if (colors == 0) {
        textview.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Vanilla));
        linear.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Maroon));
        textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0,
                (getResources().getColor(R.color.Maroon)));
    } else if (colors == 1) {
        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
    } else if (colors == 2) {
        textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setShadowLayer((float) 1.5, 2, 2, Color.WHITE);
    }
```

where is my fault
any help???

Answer (score 0):

You are writing and reading from two different SharedPreferences:

In SettingsActivity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In prayers:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
        "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Notice the first parameter i.e., the name of the SharedPreference file.

Comment: I changed the second and I write ite like the first one but it doesn't work the colors don't change

Comment: In which order are the activities presented? Does restarting the app reflect the changes made in previous invocation?